# Render data from DynamoDB in Jinja template

Tags: python, json, flask, jinja2, boto3

I have a Flask route that authenticates and connects to AWS DynamoDB using boto3 and pulls an entire table by scanning it, returning the result as JSON.  I want to render the results as HTML instead, but passing the JSON to `render_template` doesn't work, I get a 500 internal server error.  How do I render the data?

```
@app.route("/x/")
def x():
    #Authentication and connection omitted
    table = dynamodb.Table(table_name)
    response = table.scan()
    js = json.dump(response)
    #return js
    return render_template('test.html', data=js)
```

```html
<ul>
{% for item in data %}
    <li>{{ item.Make}}</li>
    <li>{{ item.Model}}</li>
    <li>{{ item.Year}}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I want to output the data like this:

```
Honda
Civic
2013

Toyota
Camry
1999
```

JSON data:

```
{
  "Count": 2, 
  "Items": [
    {
      "Make": "Honda", 
      "Model": "Civic", 
      "Year": "2013"
    }, 
    {
      "Make": "Toyota", 
      "Model": "Camry", 
      "Year": "1999"
    }
  ], 
  "ResponseMetadata": {
    "HTTPStatusCode": 200, 
    "RequestId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  }, 
  "ScannedCount": 2
}
```

Comment: if your response is js, it is loads(str) that returns a dict from string. Else if it was a dict, you don't have to dump it, pass it to the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to render the data in HTML, don't dump it to a JSON string.  The data you have is a dictionary, iterating over it doesn't make sense in this context.  You want to iterate over the value of `items` in that dictionary.

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    ...
    response = table.scan()
    return render_template('index.html', data=data)
```

```html
<table>
<thead><tr><th>Make</th><th>Model></th><th>Year</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>{% for item in data['items'] %}<tr>
    <td>{% item['Make'] %}</td>
    <td>{% item['Model'] %}</td>
    <td>{% item['Year'] %}</td>
</tr>{% endfor %}</tbody>
</table>
```